# How do I remove the first character in N lines in vim?

Tags: vim

When I paste into vim I often get a `#` character at the start of each line I've pasted.

Is there an easy way I can remove the first char on N lines (without regex)?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `set paste` when pasting into vim

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514445/turning-off-auto-indent-when-pasting-text-into-vim/2514520#2514520

Comment: Cursor on first character to delete, `<ctrl>v`, move to the last character to delete, `x` (`<ctrl>v` starts column-wise selection in visual mode).

Answer (score 6):

Go to the first occurrence of `#` in the pasted text.

Enter blockwise visual mode.

```
ctrl-V
```

Select first character in each line pasted.

```
<count>j
```

where count = N - 1

Delete the selected text.

```
x
```

Btw, your concern should have been to avoid getting `#` altogether when  you paste. The solution to which is `:set paste`

Answer (score 6):

**Method 1:**

Select these N lines and press `:`, the command line will look like this

```
:'<,'>
```

complete the command as `:'<,'>normal x` and press `Enter`

**Method 2:**

Say the the number of first line and last line you pasted in are *startNumber* and  *endNumber*, just use command line:

```
:startNumber,endNumber normal x
```