# Map <S-Insert> to paste content of clipboard in a filetype

Tags: vim, key-bindings, gnome-terminal

I want to use `<S-Insert>` to paste the content of clipboard in `vim` irrespective me being in `normal` or `insert` mode

I am using [Fedora 23, **Gnome terminal 3.18.3**, vim 7.4 +xterm_clipboard]

---

The usual problem I have is:

1. I go on the web and Ctrl-C on multiple lines
2. Back to vim in Insert or Normal mode I want to paste **WITHOUT** indentation modification

And I get a paste with a messed up indentation but only when the file being copied to as a `filetype` like r/python (I guess because an indent is defined)

---

**What I have found**

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514445/turning-off-auto-indent-when-pasting-text-into-vim) (amongst others) but that's not working.

**How I can make it work**

When I use the `paste` mode it works
For example if I do

1. I go on the web and Ctrl-C on multiple lines
2. In vim :set paste
3. I do `<S-Insert>`

Then it works **irrespective of mode OR filetype** and I can `:set nopaste`

Another way is to paste from clipboard `"+p` which works (without messing with `paste` mode)

**Leads ??**

Thing is I am not even sure this is `vim` related, I think I cannot map `<S-Insert>` as if I do

```
nnoremap <S-Insert> <NOP>
inoremap <S-Insert> <NOP>
vnoremap <S-Insert> <NOP>
```

And start new terminal then vim and try `<S-Insert>` it still copies

Answer (score 0):

> I get a paste with a messed up indentation

This is because vim assumes the copied text as a stream of characters typed in to it.

If you can use system clipboard in vim, use these mappings

```
:map <silent> <S-Insert> "+p
:imap <silent> <S-Insert> <Esc>"+pa
```

You can find if vim has clipboard support using

```
vim --version
```

If you see "+xterm_clipboard", you are good to go. Use it with

```
set clipboard=unnamed  " or
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

If using system keyboard is out of the picture, my suggestion would be to write a function that takes you to paste mode with `set paste`, pastes the copied text, takes you back to normal mode with `set nopaste`

Comment: I do have `+xterm_clipboard` unfortunately your fix is not working for me

Comment: Can you try `:map <silent> <S-Insert> "*p`  ?  ie, `*` instead of `+`

Comment: Does `"*p` or `"+p` paste the text in clipboard?

Comment: Hello `:map <silent> <S-Insert> "*p` does not work, but "vanilla" pasting from clipboard `"+p` DOES work