# New lines being inserted at the start of the lines when pasted in vim (tmux)

Tags: vim, formatting, command-prompt, tmux

I use Tmux to open my terminals . When I copy and paste in Tmux, new lines are being attached at the start of the lines. For example if I copy :

```
Line1 to be copied.
Line2 to be copied.
Line3 to be copied.
```

And if I paste the above text. It would become

```
Line1 to be copied.
    Line2 to be copied.
         Line3 to be copied.
```

I use it from mac. I select the text to be copied while pressing "alt" key and then paste it. Any suggestions on how to avoid the spaces at the start?

Note: A few more details about the environment.
I have a custom tmux.conf file. Following are a few setting I use in my tmux conf.

```
# more settings to make copy-mode more vim-like
unbind [
bind Escape copy-mode
unbind p
bind p paste-buffer
bind -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
bind -t vi-copy 'z' copy-pipe "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
# Buffers to/from Mac clipboard, yay tmux book from pragprog
bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
bind C-v run "tmux set-buffer $(reattach-to-user-namespace pbpaste); tmux paste-buffer")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question looks like it has been already asked.

[Turning off auto indent when pasting text into vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514445/turning-off-auto-indent-when-pasting-text-into-vim)

**Sum up:**
Try typing:

```
    :set paste
```

before pasting your clipboard and then return it to

```
    :set nopaste
```

after, in order to resume normal formatting when entering newlines.

Answer (score 2):

To make this automatic, you can use [vim-bracketed-paste](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/vim-bracketed-paste)