# Vim indents every line of code when copying-pasting

Tags: vim, indentation

When I copy and past a block of code in Vim, every line gets indented by one. For example, I have this source:

```
    print "Hello"
    print "World"
    print "I'm copying"
    print "and pasting"
```

Which gets jumbled when pasting into Vim:

```
print "Hello"
        print "World"
            print "I'm copying"
                print "and pasting"
```

For copying long lines of code, it's very frustrating because everything gets out of alignment (not good for python).

Here is my vimrc. It currently auto-indents on newlines, and replaces tabs with the standard 4 spaces.

```
filetype plugin indent on
" show existing tab with 4 spaces width
set tabstop=4
" when indenting with '>', use 4 spaces width
set shiftwidth=4
" On pressing tab, insert 4 spaces
set expandtab
```

While this config works, something is causing the copy-paste problem. How can this be fixed, but still retain the behaviors that I've defined?

Comment: have you tried using the paste option? `:set paste` before you paste the code in vim

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning off auto indent when pasting text into vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514445/turning-off-auto-indent-when-pasting-text-into-vim)

Comment: `:r !cat` followed by `^D` avoids the need to switch in an out of any modes or set/unset an options.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `:set paste` to switch to paste mode.

[This article explains paste mode](https://blog.ayaz.pk/paste-mode-pasting-text-and-indenting-it-in-vim-3b9091891038#.ung9h9egc)

It was made specifically for pasting text into vim so it doesn't trigger any input mappings. Remember to `:set nopaste` when you are done to get your mappings back.

Comment: When pasting text Vim doesn't have any way to differentiate between a sequence of key strokes that you typed and pre-formatted lines that you are pasting unless you tell it. The author of the linked article seems unaware that TAB characters are *not* something any "sane" Python programmer would use. TAB characters should never be used in Python source code. https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/  Unfortunately popular discussion of this matter seems very badly informed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120926/why-does-python-pep-8-strongly-recommend-spaces-over-tabs-for-indentation