# Why does Vim indent every line once more when I copy and paste text from my browser to a file?

Tags: vim

Why do I get this when I copy some text from a browser window into a file I'm editing with Vim?  How do I get the lines to line up properly?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

# Create your models here.
class WorldBorder(models.Model):
        # Regular Django fields corresponding to the attributes in the
            # world borders shapefile.
                name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
                    area = models.IntegerField()
                        pop2005 = models.IntegerField('Population 2005')
                            fips = models.CharField('FIPS Code', max_length=2)
                                iso2 = models.CharField('2 Digit ISO', max_length=2)
                                    iso3 = models.CharField('3 Digit ISO', max_length=3)
                                        un = models.IntegerField('United Nations Code')
                                            region = models.IntegerField('Region Code')
                                                subregion = models.IntegerField('Sub-Region Code')
                                                    lon = models.FloatField()
                                                        lat = models.FloatField()
                                                             # GeoDjango-specific: a geometry field (MultiPolygonField)
                                                                mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField()
                                                                     # Returns the string representation of the model.
                                                                       def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
                                                                                    return self.name
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning off auto indent when pasting text into vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514445/turning-off-auto-indent-when-pasting-text-into-vim)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have either `autoindent` or `cindent` on. When you have one of those options on, Vim doesn't know the difference between the newlines that get pasted into the terminal and those you enter yourself. Therefore, when you paste a newline, Vim indents the line, and then you also paste whitespace providing an additional indent, and so on with the next line, until you're much farther over on the screen than you want.

The solution is to use `:set paste` to set paste mode and then paste, then `:set nopaste` to turn paste mode off. While in paste mode, Vim doesn't autoindent lines, so pasting a large number of lines into the terminal doesn't cause ever-increasing indents.

If you have a Vim with clipboard support on your particular platform, you can also paste using the `"*` and `"+` registers (e.g. with `"*p` to paste), which won't have that problem, either.

Comment: another way to achieve the same result: `:set noai` do disable `autoindent` mode, `:set ai` to enable it again