# How do I eliminate cascading indents when pasting text in nano?

Tags: indentation, nano

## Background

I am doing a simple copy paste from one shell to another. Below is an example set of text I would copy from a code file:

```
code
code 
  code 
code code
```

However, when pasted, the text comes out like this in a nano editor

```
code
  code
      code
        code code
```

For each new line, it keeps indenting the pasted code in the editor. It is exactly the problem faced in this [vim autoindenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514445/turning-off-auto-indent-when-pasting-text-into-vim) question however, I am not familiar with the equivalent nano setting, hence why I am asking the question.

## Question

How do I prevent the cascading indenting issue that I am experiencing above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [`nano`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) and [`vim`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) derive from different text editors, the [`~/.nanorc`](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.1/nanorc.5.html) file for nano as well as the [manually created `~/.vimrc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921441/where-is-my-vimrc-file) for vim have idential keywords that perform identical functions.  One such instance of this identicality happens with the `autoindent` keyword.  Remove the line that states `set autoindent` in your `~/.nanorc` file and see if that resolves the issue.

**NOTE:** You will be unable to autoindent while typing if you use this method. But if that does not concern you, follow the solution above.